# DataGridColumns with different ItemsSources

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, multibinding

I want to create a **DataGrid** with two columns (X and Y), being that each may be populated by different collections.

The Y column is always populated with the Y data from an **ObservableCollection(NPoint)**, where **NPoint** is a class with X and Y properties.

The X column starts being populated with the "default" values defined elsewhere (an **ObservableCollection(double)**). This "default" collection belongs to a singleton class. However, depending on the `.IsChecked` of a nearby **CheckBox**, the X column might be populated with the X data from the same collection as the Y data.

The latter case is trivial, since both columns will share the same ItemsSource. However, how can one bind one column of a **DataGrid** to one object and another column to another object? Is there a way to bind the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to two different collections? Can this be done with **Multi-** or **PriorityBinding**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading @techhero's answer, I had a crazy idea which I managed to pull off (thanks to [Tao Ling's answer to this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/38413d0a-7388-4191-a7a6-fd66e469d502/two-listbox-scrollbar-in-synchronisation?forum=wpf)). It isn't perfect, but it does the trick. I basically split the **DataGrid** into two, one with the X column (with variable `.ItemsSource`) and one with the Y column, one right next to the other.

Here's the relevant code:

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0"
            x:Name="CoordinatesX"
            LoadingRow="RowIndexX"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" x:Name="XColumn"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1"
            x:Name="CoordinatesY"
            ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Points, ElementName=CableTab}" 
            LoadingRow="RowIndexY"
            RowHeaderWidth="0"
            ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="ScrollChanged"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**.CS**

```
private void RowIndexX(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString();
}
private void RowIndexY(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Header = " ";
}
void ControlBindings()
{
    var resultSections = NProjectProperties.Instance.ResultSections;
    var cable = DataContext as NCable;
    Binding binding;
    if (EqualToResults.IsChecked == true)
    {
        CoordinatesX.ItemsSource = resultSections;
        XColumn.IsReadOnly = true;
        XColumn.Foreground = Brushes.DarkGray;
        binding = new Binding();
    }
    else
    {
        CoordinatesX.ItemsSource = cable.Points;
        XColumn.IsReadOnly = false;
        XColumn.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        binding = new Binding("X");
    }
    binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
    binding.NotifyOnValidationError = true;
    XColumn.Binding = binding;
}
private void EqualToResultsChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ControlBindings();
}
private void ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var scroll1 = NU.GetDescendantByType(CoordinatesX, typeof(ScrollViewer)) as ScrollViewer;
    var scroll2 = NU.GetDescendantByType(CoordinatesY, typeof(ScrollViewer)) as ScrollViewer;
    scroll1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scroll2.VerticalOffset);
}

public static class NU
{
    public static Visual GetDescendantByType(Visual element, Type type)
    {
        if (element == null) return null;
        if (element.GetType() == type) return element;
        Visual foundElement = null;
        if (element is FrameworkElement)
        {
            (element as FrameworkElement).ApplyTemplate();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
        {
            Visual visual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as Visual;
            foundElement = GetDescendantByType(visual, type);
            if (foundElement != null)
                break;
        }
        return foundElement;
    }
}
```

[image: Resulting window]

The `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="ScrollChanged"` line is what allows the **DataGrids** to scroll together.
However, the first **DataGrid** has a row header, which for some reason makes the rows slightly bigger. This means that, if the second one wasn't given a header, they wouldn't be aligned. Therefore the second **DataGrid** is given a LoadingRowY function which returns an " " header which doesn't appear since the `RowHeaderWidth="0"`. This does however make the rows be drawn in the same scale as those of the first **DataGrid**, aligning them.

As can be seen, the space between the two **DataGrids** isn't very nice and clean and should be improved, but I'm satisfied for now.